# iOS UITableView - Sections inside sections

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to create sections inside sections, in UITableView, like this:

```
section Year
   section Month
      cell day
      cell day
      cell day
      cell day
```

and sections must be collapsible.  I have array with data which I'll group, first by the months, then by years. I know how to do sections on one level nesting, but with two levels nesting I don't know is it tableview inside tablecell good solution, or there is better solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, probably the best way to keep the code clean is creating a subclass of UIView which contains a table for the days. Then add instances of this UIview to the cells in the table that contains the years. That should allow you to separate the code for each table.